# Unit Testing $routeParams in directive

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, jasmine, angular-mock

I have a directive that accesses the `$routeParams` of the page as such:

```
myApp.directive("myList", function ($routeParams) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'tabs/my-list.html',
        link: function (scope) {
            scope.year = $routeParams.year;
       }
    };
});
```

The directive works as expected and correctly accesses the `$routeParams`

I am trying to test using angular-mock/jasmine.  I can't figure out how to pass mock `$routeParams` to the directive.  This is what I have:

```
describe('myList', function () {
    var scope, compile, element, compiledDirective;
    var mockParams = { 'year': 1996 };

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('templates', 'MyApp');

        inject(function ($compile, $rootScope, $routeParams) {
            compile = $compile;
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
        });
        element = angular.element('<my-list></my-list>');
        compiledDirective = compile(element)(scope);
        scope.$digest();
    });
    it('should fill in the year', function () {
        expect(scope.year).toEqual(mockParams.year);
    });
});
```

Which obviously doesn't work because I never passed passed `mockParams` to the directive. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: How about just using `$routeParams.year = 1996;` before creating the element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mock the `$routeParams` object `mockParams` using `angular.extend` **OR** do assign `mockParams` object directly to `$routeParams`. In that way `$routeParams` will be available before directive gets compiled.

```
inject(function ($compile, $rootScope, $routeParams) {
    compile = $compile;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    angular.extend($routeParams, mockParams);
});
```